# Can custom text be set for columns.filterable.multi in Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using columns.filterable.multi feature for a kendo grid (JQuery). I'm using this feature on a boolean field. The values for the checkboxes has to be true and false for it to work. Looks like crap. Is there way to create custom text for the check boxes so it looks more professional (Approved, Not Approved)?

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "isapproved",
    filterable: {
        multi:true,
        dataSource: [{isapproved: true},{isapproved: false}]
    }
  } ]});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the so called messages in your grid definition: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/filterable.messages#filterable.messages.isTrue

Comment: Not the right solution for my issue (messages), but the page you pointed me to, solved my issue: itemTemplate: {return "my html"}. Thanks.